# mutiple image upload using multiple input

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload multiple files from multiple input element for an online application form. I can upload one image using the below script please share how I can upload multiple image using multiple input??

```
if(!empty($_FILES)){
    include 'config.php';
    $file = $_FILES['image_file'];
    $file_name = $file['name'];
    $error = ''; // Empty
    $ext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, "."), 1));

    if($validation_type == 1)   
    {
        $file_info = getimagesize($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name']);
        if(empty($file_info)) // No Image?      
        {
            $error .= "The uploaded file doesn't seem to be an image.";              
        }
        else // An Image?      
        {
            $file_mime = $file_info['mime'];
            if ($ext == 'jpc' || $ext == 'jpx' || $ext == 'jb2')         
            {
                $extension = $ext;         
            }
            else
            {
                $extension = ($mime[$file_mime] == 'jpeg') ? 'jpg' : $mime[$file_mime];
            }    
            if(!$extension)
            {
                $extension = '';  
                $file_name = str_replace('.', '', $file_name); 
            }     
        }   
    }
    else if($validation_type == 2)
    {     
        if (!in_array($ext, $image_extensions_allowed))
        {
            $exts = implode(', ',$image_extensions_allowed);
            $error .= "You must upload a file with one of the following extensions:".$exts;
        }
        $extension = $ext;   
    }

    if($error == "") // No errors were found?
    {
        $new_file_name = strtolower($file_name);
        $new_file_name = str_replace(' ', '-', $new_file_name);
        $new_file_name = substr($new_file_name, 0, -strlen($ext));
        $new_file_name .= $extension;   // File Name
        $move_file = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],     
        $upload_image_to_folder.$new_file_name);
        if($move_file)
        {
           $done = 'The image has been uploaded.';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        @unlink($file['tmp_name']);
    }
    $file_uploaded = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML as well?

Comment: Have you used `multiple` attribute on the `<input type="file">` and done a var_dump in PHP for $_FILES ?

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for multiple browse buttons, try your field name like this:

```
<input type="file" name="image_file1[]" />
<input type="file" name="image_file1[]" />
<input type="file" name="image_file1[]" />
<input type="file" name="image_file2[]" />
<input type="file" name="image_file2[]" />
<input type="file" name="image_file2[]" />
```

and then

```
                if(!empty($_FILES['image_file1']['name'])){                 
                $uploaded_file = $_FILES['image_file1'];
                for($fi=0; $fi<count($_FILES['image_file1']['name']); $fi++){
                   $file_name= $uploaded_file['name'][$fi];
                   $file_type= $uploaded_file['type'][$fi];
                   $tmp_name= $uploaded_file['tmp_name'][$fi];
                   $file_size= $uploaded_file['size'][$fi];
                }
                }



                if(!empty($_FILES['image_file2']['name'])){                 
                $uploaded_file = $_FILES['image_file2'];
                for($fi=0; $fi<count($_FILES['image_file2']['name']); $fi++){
                   $file_name= $uploaded_file['name'][$fi];
                   $file_type= $uploaded_file['type'][$fi];
                   $tmp_name= $uploaded_file['tmp_name'][$fi];
                   $file_size= $uploaded_file['size'][$fi];
                }
                }
```

Comment: Need different input names for each upload. And store to different folder.

Comment: no problem, i edit this solution and you can try this
You can use different folders for both fields